# How to not shown selected item in spinner...?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to not shown selected item in spinner and my spinner is looks like this...![image: my spinner background is just arrow which you can see behind the text image description here]

my spinner background is only the arrow which you can see behind the text...please help me...thanks in advance..

Comment: So, what you want to show there ?

Comment: Why you using spinner ?? you can also use another control..

Comment: after selecting the item from spinner i set the selected text in Edittext...but i dont want to show the selected item in spinner because it hides my background image which is arrow image....

Comment: thats why I am asking why you using spinner???

Comment: so, which control i can use...?

Comment: i checked that answer but whichButton has value -1 so, we can not show array data in textview..?

Comment: i want array position in click of "OK" of alertDialog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suggest that You can use `ImageView` & `AlertDialog` instead of `Spinner`.

Just open AlertDialog on ImageView and display your data in AlertDialog (SingleChoice) and setText which your item selected in AlertDialog.

Here is sample code of AlertDialog.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

.setSingleChoiceItems(items,0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        textview.setText(items[which])
    }
})
.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           }
})
.show();
```

Where items is String[] of your data. Call this code in `OnClick` of `ImageView`.

You can also check [How to add list in dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Comment: but whichButton has value -1 so, we can not show correct data and it show the error....

Answer (score 0):

```
spinnerSildeMenu
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                arg0.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide any item in the spinner dropdown you need to pass the position of item which needs to hided based on criteria required.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private List<String> dates;
private int hideItemPostion;

public CustomAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<String> dates) {
    super(context, resource,dates);
    this.dates=dates;
}
public void setItemToHide(int itemToHide)
{
    this.hideItemPostion =itemToHide;
}
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    if (position == hideItemPostion) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv.setHeight(0);
        v = tv;
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
        v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
    return v;
}}
```

And setting the adapter is as below

```
final CustomAdapter dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_item,dates);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.setItemToHide(0);
```

On selecting some items from the dropdown also the position needs to changed. On your case the required item is selected item and for that the selected position needs to be passed to adapter.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mEPGDateSelector.setSelection(i);
        dataAdapter.setItemToHide(i);}

         @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```